# How use function _wsplitpath C++

Tags: c++, file, path, wstring

I have such code

```
wstring filename;
wstring dirname;
wstring disk;
```

then I want to split the fullpath to the file this way

```
_wsplitpath(&filepath[0],&disk[0],&dirname[0],NULL,NULL);
```

but I have an exception. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `_wsplitpath_s` which prevents buffer overflows. Also use vectors which return pointers to mutable characters and initialize them with sizes:

```
std::wstring filename;
std::vector<wchar_t> disk(8);
std::vector<wchar_t> dirname(1024);

_wsplitpath_s(
    filename.c_str(),
    disk.data(), disk.size(),
    dirname.data(), dirname.size(),
    nullptr, 0,
    nullptr, 0
);
```

Comment: filename.c_str() isn't siut, because filename contain Unicode-string

Comment: `filename.c_str()` returns exactly the same thing as `&filename[0]` does, except it’s `CharT const*` instead of `CharT*` (which doesn’t matter here).

Comment: @ПавелВоевода `c_str()` stands for "C string" -- i.e. null-terminated. Not "char string". it works fine with `wstring`.

Comment: No. `std::wstring` is an alias for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string.